# Facebook returned an error: OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login, hybridauth

I am getting this issue while logging in sometime, After search I got that its related to something session/cookie that already exist of previous login. But still couldn't found the solution.

here is my code:

```
        $auth = new \Hybrid_Auth(Yii::$app->params['hybridConfig']);

        $adapter = $auth->authenticate($provider);

        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();

        $accessToken = $adapter->getAccessToken();
        $adapter->logout();
```

and In hybrid lib facebook provider code:

```
try{
        $fields = array(
            'id', 'name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'link', 'website',
            'gender', 'locale', 'about', 'email', 'hometown', 'location'
        );
        $data = $this->api->api('/me?fields=' . implode(',', $fields))

    }
    catch( FacebookApiException $e ){

        throw new Exception( "User profile request failed! {$this->providerId} returned an error: $e", 6 );
    }
```